# Understanding operator() overloading with min stl priority_queue

Tags: c++, stl, operator-overloading, priority-queue

i have been studying on priority_queue. when i tried to create a min stl priority_queue, i searched on net and found some tutorial. but i don't understand a few things in the code.
so far i have the following code.

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<iostream>
#include<queue>
using namespace std;
class compare
{
public:
    bool operator()(const int &a, const int &b)
    {
        return a>b;
    }
};
int main()
{
    priority_queue<int, vector<int>, compare > pq;
    int i,n;
    for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
    {
        pq.push(i);
    }
    while(!pq.empty())
    {
        cout<<pq.top()<<endl;
        pq.pop();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

questions:

1. in the operator function there are two parameters but, when i push element in the queue there is only 1 argument then how this works and compare ?
2. what does the declaration of `pq` mean ? i mean why there is `<vector<int>>` and what does it mean and do ?

Comment: `push` doesn't have two parameters, only one, and that's what you call when pushing an element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in the operator function there are two parameters but, when i push element in the queue there is only 1 argument then how this works and compare ?

The comparator is used by the priority queue to compare elements to determine which has the higher priority. When you push an element, it compares it with elements already in the queue to determine where to position the new element.

In this case, the comparator says that the element with the greater value has the greater priority.

> what does the declaration of pq mean ? i mean why there is `<vector<int>>` and what does it mean and do ?

`priority_queue` is a *container adapter*. It uses a container for storage, and adds extra functionality - in this case, extraction in priority order. `vector<int>` specifies that it should use a `vector` as its storage; that's the default, and you should use that unless you have a good reason not to.

Comment: that means the comparator takes the top element of the priority_queue as left hand operand ?

Comment: @KhairulBasar: It might do. In general, it will call the comparator whenever it needs to compare the priority of two elements of the queue.

Comment: another question, when it takes an element does it compare with all the existed elements in the queue ?

Comment: @KhairulBasar Not all of them. Heap insertion (via `std::push_heap`, which `push()` uses) is required to be `O(log n)` or better.